# For 2 functions $f$ and $g$ in $E$, let $d(f,g) = \max\limits_{x \in [a,b]}|f(x)-g(x)|$. Prove that $(E,d)$ is a metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, function-spaces

Let $E$ be the set of all real-valued continuous functions on $[a,b]$ and for 2 functions $f$ and $g$ in $E$, let $d(f,g) = \displaystyle\max_{x \in [a,b]}|f(x)-g(x)|$. Prove that $(E,d)$ is a metric space.

I know how to prove the first 3 properties of a metric space, but I do not know how to prove the triangle inequality.

Comment: What do you mean by $f(g)$ in the definition of $d$? Do you mean $g(x)$?

Comment: Do you know that triangle inequality on $\mathbb{R}$, with the usual metric?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer No, $d(f,g)$ is the correct thing to write. The metric $d$ is defined on $E$, a set of function. So, its arguments should be functions $f, g$, and not $f(x), g(x)$ (which are real numbers for each $x$). e: formatting

Comment: I was talking about within the argument of the $\max$ function. Not that of the function $d$. Notably the edits to the question seem to align with what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f,g,h\in E$. We need to show that $d(f,h)\leqslant d(f,g) + d(g,h)$.

For any $x\in [a,b]$ we have $$|f(x)-h(x)| = |f(x) -g(x) + g(x) - h(x)| \leqslant |f(x)-g(x)| + |g(x)-h(x)|. $$
Taking the $\max$ over $[a,b]$ it follows that
$$
\max_{x\in[a,b]} |f(x)-h(x)| \leqslant \max_{x\in[a,b]}(|f(x)-g(x)| + |g(x)-h(x)|).
$$
Now, since $$\max_{x\in[a,b]}(|f(x)-g(x)|+|g(x)-h(x)|) \leqslant \max_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)-g(x)| + \max_{x\in[a,b]}|g(x)-h(x)|, $$
we have
$$
d(f,h) = \max_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)-h(x)| \leqslant \max_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)-g(x)| + \max_{x\in[a,b]}|g(x)-h(x)| = d(f,g) + d(g,h),
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 1):

$|f(x)-h(x)| \le |f(x)-g(x)|+|g(x)-h(x)| \le d(f,g)+f(g,h)$.

Now take the $\sup$ over $x$ to get the desired result.

Comment: This leaves out one subtle detail, that $\sup_{x\in[a,b]}(|f(x)-g(x)| + |g(x)-h(x)|) $ is not in general equal to $d(f,g)+d(g,h)$, but instead is $\leqslant d(f,g)+d(g,h)$. I addressed this in my answer. I don't know that it harms the validity of the proof necessarily, but I thought it to be worth mentioning.

Comment: I am missing your point. I never said they were equal? We have $|f(x)-g(x)| \le d(f,g)$ and similarly for $|g(x)-h(x)|$ by definition of $d(\cdot,\cdot)$.

Comment: @Math1000: Btw, I get a 403 when I follow your link :-).

Comment: You don’t need that, though. @Math1000 You know from this that $|f(x)-h(x)|\leq d(f,g)+d(g,h)$ so the supremum of the left side is also $\leq d(f,g)+d(g,h).$

Comment: I didn't post a link? And @ThomasAndrews I suppose you are correct. Again I am being needlessly pedantic :)

Comment: @Math1000: Your bio...

Comment: Oh, keithbelcher.com? I don't have anything there right now. 403 error is the correct result. Maybe some day I will get around to actually making a website.

Comment: Web irony I guess...